# How to install an XAP from the commandline in a windows mobile 7 standalone emulator?

Tags: windows-phone-7, emulation, datastore

We have installed a windows phone stand alone emulator XDE.exe.

Now we would like to install from the commandline additional windows mobile applications.

For this we used the Smart Device Connectivity API as described in Justin Angel's blog post [1].

This is working fine as long as we have a complete SDK installed.

If we try to install an application on the stand alone emulator we face an error because the datastore is empty [2].

Any idea how the stand alone emulator can be added to the datastore? Or do you know an other approach to install an XAP inside a stand alone emulator?

Thanks for a hint.

Best Regards
Frank

[1] http://justinangel.net/WindowsPhone7EmulatorAutomation

[2] Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.PlatformNotFoundExceptio
n: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.PlatformNotFoundExcepti
on' was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/).  If you download the code you can tweek the WindowsPhonePowerTools.Console to do what  you want.  Out of the box it seems to have a problem with the way it parses the command line causing full paths to a xap having a ':' on them to not work so well (could be fixed pretty easy though).

To test it out, I copied a xap file to the directory I compiled the WindowsPhonePowerTools.Console to and used the following command line to deploy to the emulator:

wptools.exe -target:emulator -xap:myxapname.xap -install

Comment: Thanks for your interesting link. But this tool has the same issue: It does not know the stand alone emulator because it is not in the datastore :-(.

Comment: What are you using as the name to check the data store for the emulator?

Comment: Hello Jason, Kindly find my reply above (Answer 2) Frank

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402565%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

XapDeployCmd.exe has the following syntax:

XapDeployCmd.exe

The following table describes the command-line options for XapDeployCmd.exe.

Option

Description

Specifies the command to run. This option has one of the following values:
OptionDescription
/installlaunch - Installs and runs the app on the device. This option requires the Xap FileName argument.
/update - Updates the app already installed on the device. This option requires the Xap FileName argument.
/launch - Launches the app already installed on the device. This option requires the Product ID argument.
/uninstall - Uninstalls the app from the device. This option requires the Product ID argument.
/EnumerateDevices - Lists the valid device targets and a numeric index for each device.

- Specifies the GUID of the app. This value is found in the app manifest file for the project, WMAppManifest.xml.

- Specifies the full path of the XAP to be installed or updated.

- Specifies the target device. This option has one of the following values:

xd - Default emulator.
de - Windows Phone device connected to the development computer.
n - The device at index n in the list of devices. To get the list of devices, run XapDeployCmd.exe /EnumerateDevices.